# Facebook iOS SDK causing crashes

Tags: ios, facebook

We are experiencing a lot of crashes in our app (Reporting by Crashlytics, but the devs haven't been able to reproduce). The stack trace suggests that this is caused by facebook sdk (3.15.1). 
Is this a known issue in the older versions?

We are trying to see whether we should submit a new version with latest version of SDK, or investigate this further.

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.root.default-priority
0  ???                            0x2be030c4 
1  ???                            0x2be03f07 
2  ???                            0x2be0569f 
3  libdyld.dylib                  0x394c80d0 dyld_stub_binder + 20
4  Couchsurfing                   0x0035c901 __31+[FBTask taskDependentOnTasks:]_block_invoke (FBTask.m:96)
5  Couchsurfing                   0x0035d6bd __39-[FBTask dependentTaskWithBlock:queue:]_block_invoke_2 (FBTask.m:257)
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x394a3d7b _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x394b6989 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 220
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x394b6b79 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 56
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x395e5dbf _pthread_wqthread + 298
```

Comment: Releasing a hot fix with the updated version to see if the crashes go aeway

Comment: Did the updated version fix the issue?

Comment: @bruce.cheek No it didn't fix the issue, this crash is specific to iOS versions below 7.1 Still investigating

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case you are using cocoapods, make sure you have set on your Podfile the build version correctly.

i.e: The line your app is crashing

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
```

The line your app is crashing uses the method `OSAtomicDecrement32` that has a different implementation for iOS 7.1 and above.